# Adding two-dimensional arrays in angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning basic javascript here, please help, working on adding two-dimensional arrays, where 0th index will be always date and 1st index will be always integer in array, what i am trying to achieve is produce a new array with unique objects type=A and type=B by adding its 1st index of two-dimensional arrays. see below for example code

```
 $scope.mainArray = [{
    type: 'A',
    values: [
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 11],
      [111111, 2],
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    values: [
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 11],
      [111111, 2],
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'A',
    values: [
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 11],
      [111111, 2],
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    values: [
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 12],
      [111111, 11],
      [111111, 2],
    ]
  }, ];

Should convert to

  $scope.newArray = [{
    type:'A',
    values:[
      [11111,24],
      [11111,24],
      [11111,22],
      [11111,4],
      ]
  },{
    type:'B',
    values:[
      [11111,24],
      [11111,24],
      [11111,22],
      [11111,4],
      ]
  }];
```

Plunker [`link`](https://plnkr.co/edit/cWVKbYj9ogotqIkimeHY)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you run through this tutorial I believe you'll learn how to accomplish this. http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you updated the snippet so here is an example of using map/filter/reduce to get the output you're looking for.

```
  $scope.typeAArray = $scope.mainArray.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.type === 'A';
  }).reduce(function (a, b) {
    var newObj = {
      type: a.type,
      values: []
    };
    a.values.map(function (v, index) {
      newObj.values.push(v);
      newObj.values[index][1] += b.values[index][1];
    });
    return newObj;
  });
```